How to tune the classification threshold in a cost-sensitive manner?
I have trained a classifier outputting probabilities for each class. I want to tune the decision threshold in such a way that it accounts for different costs/gains assigned to false positives ($FP$), $FN$, $TP$, and $TN$.
Is there a streamlined way of doing this in scikit-learn?

The recent release of scikit-learn (May 2024, v1.5.0) introduces a new feature that facilitates cost-sensitive learning: TunedThresholdClassifierCV.
Its fixed-threshold sibling is FixedThresholdClassifier, allowing one to easily override the default 0.5 decision threshold. The release highlights motivate and outline these new additions.
They also include a new tutorial "Post-tuning the decision threshold for cost-sensitive learning", covering both constant and non-constant misclassification costs when tuning a classifier during cost-sensitive learning. A more basic tutorial on the new functionality is also available. The User Guide §3.3 has a relevant section as well.
